# Centering an SVG inside the border bottom

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a website using WordPress. My client needs a similar design to be created in WordPress. In design, there are blog posts that are separated by a divider. Check the screenshot, I want to create something similar to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG4Nr.png

I am confused about how to cut a border in two halves and place an SVG in the center. Will someone guide me on how to do that? Need it done via CSS.

### Class Name: .ast-separate-container .ast-article-post

I was using Astra theme! Thanks to [botivegh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11329034/botivegh) for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example how to achieve this, just adjust to your own classes:

```html
<style>
  div.your-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  hr.your-hr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  
  .your-img {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://svgur.com/i/byb.svg);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: center center;
  }
</style>


<div class="your-container">
  <hr class="your-hr" />
  <div class="your-img"></div>
  <hr class="your-hr" />
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm leaving the general answer above. But here is the css you need to add and it will do the trick. Everything is set that the image is **20px.** If you want to change that, you need to adjust the background-size, width, height and left attributes. Hope this will help.

```
.ast-separate-container .ast-article-post::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    z-index: 10;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    background-image: url(https://svgur.com/i/byb.svg);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it's breaking the website design. Can you please help, if I share the website login with you?

Comment: try to adjust the width of the *hr* and the size of the *.your-img* div. I think, you just need to find the right spot. But happy to have a look into, if you share a screenshot with the web inspector open.

Comment: I see, let me have a look.

Comment: @ArbabAli I edited my answer above, you can find the css in there. Don't forget to delete or edit you comment above so others cannot sign into the you WordPress page :)

Comment: Yahooooooooo! Thanks Mate!

Comment: Can we increase icon size and remove the line from the back of SVG (like having a cut effect)? Something similar to this https://check.acefella.com/chek/

Comment: @ArbabAli sure, add .png instead with **white** background. That will do it. Also, if you change the size of the icon just adjust the background-size, width, height and left attributes accordingly. If you need help adjusting those, let me know the width of the icon and I will tell you the right settings.

Comment: I edited the SVG in Illustrator and followed the guidance. Now, it's the same as I desire. Thanks, mate, you deserve respect. 